# Comparing two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `sol1` and `cond1`. I want to compare these two lists and print values from `sol1` corresponding to `False` in `cond1`. For instance, `False` occurs at `cond1[0],cond1[2]` and the corresponding values are `sol1[0],sol1[2]`. I present the expected output.

```
sol1 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
cond1 = [False, True, False, True, True]
```

The expected output is

```
[1,4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `zip` you can iterate over pairs of items, and use a list comprehension to filter out `True` values:

```py
sol1 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
cond1 = [False, True, False, True, True]

result = [value for value, condition in zip(sol1, cond1) if not condition]
print(result)
>>> [1, 4]
```